# Creating json data from the wrapper class for use in tets classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

kindly let me know why this method is failing in test class.

```
public static string savePaitentInformation(string reqJSON){ 

    system.debug('\n--reqJSON--'+reqJSON);


    submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper objPaitentData = (submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(reqJSON, submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper.class);
    system.debug('\n--objSubmitdetails--'+objPaitentData);
    system.debug('11111 '+objPaitentData.patientDetails.Patientday);
}
```

wrapper:

```
public class submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper{
    public string providerId{get;set;}  
    public string patientId{get;set;}
    public string productId{get;set;}
    public PsOSimpleWrapper.PaitentInformationWrapper patientDetails{get;set;}

}

public class PsOSimpleWrapper{
    public class PaitentInformationWrapper{
        public string PatientfirstName {get;set;}
        public string PatientMI {get;set;}
        public string PatientlastName {get;set;}

    }
}
```

test class code:

```
public static testmethod void Test_1(){
    string psosimplejson='{"providerId":"","patientId":"","productId":"","patientDetails":[{"PatientfirstName":"","PatientMI":"","PatientlastName":"","PatientdateOfBirth":""}]}';

    string str= PsOSimpleServiceController.savePaitentInformation(psosimplejson);
    //have covered all the wrappers in test class


}
```

**Error:-System.JSONException: Expected PsOSimpleWrapper.PaitentInformationWrapper but found [line:1, column:47]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by the OP at the time I found the issue, but still thought to clarify the root cause here.

As in the original post, the JSON is declared as:

```
 string psosimplejson='{"providerId":"","patientId":"","productId":"","patientDetails":[{"PatientfirstName":"","PatientMI":"","PatientlastName":"","PatientdateOfBirth":""}]}';
```

Notice the section where `patientDetails` is being declared. The declaration is enclosed between square brackets **[]**, which is incorrect reference here as it represents arrays in a JSON format. This results in error while parsing the JSON to the appropriate class.

To resolve this, the aforementioned part needs to be declared **without the square brackets** as below:

```
patientDetails: {"PatientfirstName":"","PatientMI":"","PatientlastName":"","PatientdateOfBirth":""}
```

---

A good way to test in these cases is to create a dummy instance, populate with values and then generate the JSON for the class using [JSONGenerator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonGenerator.htm). As an example below:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeObject(myObj);
String jsonRepresentation = gen.getAsString();
```

Comment: The class could also be updated to change the property to an array by adding `[]` on the type. All depends on how the JSON is actually going to be when it comes in

Comment: That’s accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid writing raw JSON into your code. Always use JSON.serialize to make correct JSON; you'll save yourself from accidental encoding problems (like in your question), because it'll be more "obvious" when reading the code. Here's the alternative:

```
submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper wrapper = new submitPsOSimpleServiceDetailWrapper();
wrapper.providerId = '...';
wrapper.patientId = '...';
wrapper.productId = '...';
wrapper.patientDetails = new PsOSimpleWrapper.PaitentInformationWrapper();
...
String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(wrapper);
```

This method gives you compiler errors if you do anything wrong (e.g. using a list when it shouldn't be, misspellings, etc). I realize that the code is *longer*, but you get compile-time safety checks.

Comment: @sfdcfox.....thnx a lot. next time i would not post raw json data.

Answer (score -1):

got the answer
Json format was like this

```
string psosimplejson='{"providerId":"","patientId":"","productId":"","patientDetails":{"Patientday":2,"strPatientmonth":"7","Patientyear":1995}}';
```

Comment: that’s how it was and was causing issues? Or that’s how it needed to be to fix the problem. What was the reason for the problem. This answer as it stands it will not help anyone

Comment: @Eric, I actually found the root cause almost at the same time when the OP answered them self. However taking a cue from your recommendation, have provided details, which I think will be really helpful for others having similar issue. This recommendation is indeed helpful.

Comment: @Eric...yeah that's how it was. issue finally got resolved.